# Low Curie Point PTC Thermistor

Tags: thermistor

For a self regulating heater powered by a 12 V battery, I'm hoping to find a ~35 C Curie Point thermistor with a low "cold" resistance (for winter time, << 150 ohms). Most of these PTC thermistors are used for much higher temperatures and those I've found for my range have had higher resistance values than I've wanted.  Any help with the search would be appreciated, but what technology could I replace this with if I can't find an appropriate thermistor?

2-5 W is around what is needed.

Comment: An incandescent lamp, with its ~ 10:1 variation in filament resistance from cold to hot comes to mind, but what kind of power are you expecting the heater to dissipate/what temperature do you expect the heater to stabilize at?

Comment: At the Curie Point.  35 C

Comment: So, with a resistance of 150 ohms and 12V across it, it'll dissipate about a watt.  Is that what you're looking for?  Can you talk about your application?

Comment: I want to heat the air around a small window in an enclosed space. I think 0.96 W is a little low, yes. That's why I'm mainly asking for a better technology.

Comment: OK, then, I'll post an answer with a drawing in a little while.

Comment: Curie point - isn't that to do with materials losing their magnetic properties as in http://www.britannica.com/EBchecked/topic/146902/Curie-point

Comment: In the case of thermistors, the resistance spikes dramatically. I came across the names Switching Temperature and Curie Point, which, although they seemed to be different phenomena, what I found was using the two interchangeably. I would like to know more about the difference. In the case of PTC thermistors, the temperature stabilizes at the switching temperature. Also called the Curie Point (T_c on data sheets).

Answer (score 3):

Here's a 12 watt heater with a thermostat that you can adjust to get the temp you want:

**Updated graphic:**

[image]

RTH1 is an NTC thermistor with a resistance of 10k ohms at 25C, R7 is the heater; a 12 ohm resistor which'll  dissipate 12 watts with 12 volts across it, and R2 is the temperature control, which should be set to about the half-way point (5k) to start with.

Once connected to the 12 volt supply, R7 will start getting hot, and it'll heat up the space until the temperature increases to the point where the resistance of the thermistor decreases enough to cause the voltage on the inverting (-) input of U2 to become more positive than the voltage on U2's non-inverting input.

When that happens, U2's output will fall, turning OFF M1, which will allow R7 to cool.

As R7 cools, the resistance of RTH1 will increase, lowering the voltage on U2- until it falls below the voltage on U2+ , starting the cycle anew.

To adjust the temperature, measure it once it's stable and if it's too low increase R2's resistance.  If it's too high, lower the resistance.

You should use a power wirewound resistor for R7, and a couple of the types available are the vitreous enameled and the anodized aluminum housed, shown below.

[image]

I'm partial to the anodized ones because they're easy to mount to a heat spreader/heat sink and they can dissipate a lot of power for their size.  For example, the vitreous enameled one shown above is rated for 25 watts, while the housed one is rated for 50.